# Notepad changes the control characters when a StreamWriter accesses the file

Tags: c#, io, stream

When I open Notepad regulary in my windows 10 machine the control characters are the following
[image]

but when I say:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
StreamWriter jj2 = new(new FileStream("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Testing/Dude2.txt",FileMode.Truncate), Encoding.UTF8, 4096);
```

the control characters change from CRLF to 
[image]

I have tried many different configurations of the streamwriter and the underlying filestream but it is the same.
Can you please tell me why does this happen and how to change it?

Comment: In the last two years Microsoft changed the c# return to be compatible with Core (linux machines).  Changes included updating Notepad.  So CRLF is no longer used.  There is now an option in notepad (a windows registry setting) to go back to old return.  I've been having issues using Notepad since change where I do not get returns in notepad and everything is on one line.

Comment: @jdweng, Thank you. That's interesting.

Comment: Use notepad++ FTW